# Why queue of (auto-delete=true) doesn't disappear automatically after no consumer?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

The rabbitmq version is 3.1.5
Queue parameter is auto-deleted, exclusive owner is none, consumer is 0 and it is idle since yesterday.

From the web manager, I found it was still exist and waste resource.

My question is is auto-deleted mean the queue will be deleted after it is no consumer? If so, how long it will exist after no consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily,

As you can read [here](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2012-March/018986.html):

> If the queue never has consumers it 
>   will not autodelete (otherwise it would autodelete as soon as you 
>   created it).

Ayway, if you want be sure to delete your queue you can also use [QueueTTL](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl)